# How to count length of a triangle when hypotenuse is given

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I have to count the length of a triangle with 90°, 45°, 45° angles when I only know the hypotenuse. That is what I have done yet.

```
def tr(b):
a = sqrt(b*b+b*b)/2
fd(b)
lt(135)
fd(a)
lt(90)
fd(a)
lt(135)
```

Comment: Can you provide what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, welcome to StackOverflow. Kindly see [ask] questions.

Comment: sorry for wrong title of the question

Comment: You can [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/48720938/edit) and add the relevant code to it.

Comment: Nevermind I found a solution myself i will post it

Answer (score 0):

The isosceles right-angled triangle is the right-angled triangle with two equal cathets, then:

It has two angles of 45 °
It is half a square

In fact, for the corners we will have:
Right angle = 90 °
Angles at the base of the isosceles triangle = 90 ° / 2 = 45 °

For the sides we will have that, called **a** the cateti and **b** the hypotenuse is worth the theorem of Pythagoras then:

> a^2 + a^2 = b^2 2a^2 = b^2

therefore being known the value d of the hypotenuse we will have

> a^2 = b^2 / 2 a = sqrt(b^2 / 2) a = b / sqrt(2) rationalize and I
>   get a = b*sqrt(2)/2

```
a=b*2**0.5/2
```

Being instead known the value a of the cateto we will have

```
b=a*2**0.5
```